# MATLAB - iterate function on all files in a directory

Tags: matlab

I have written a MATLAB function, which works like 'myFunction('input', 'output')', in which input and output are the input and output file names respectively. I need to implement this function on all the files in a directory. Is it possible to loop through all files to implement the code on all files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) to list files in a working directory

```
%// list all text files in your folder
fls = dir( fullfile( 'path', 'to', 'my', 'folder', '*.txt' ) ); 
for ii = 1: numel(fls)
    infile = fullfile( 'path', 'to', 'my', 'folder', fls(ii).name );
    outfile = fullfile( 'path', 'to', 'my', 'folder', [fls(ii).name(1:end-4),'.DL'] ); 
    myFunction( infile, outfile );
end
```

Note how [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) command is used to concatenate paths and file name in a manner that is robust to OS environment.

Moreover, as noted by [excaza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2748311/excaza) in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942514/matlab-iterate-function-on-all-files-in-a-directory/28942679?noredirect=1#comment46143994_28942679), it is best to use [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) to separate the filename from its extension.

Comment: I was expecting another "exemplary", three-letter answer here :-)

Comment: Thank you..working well but for each output file I need a name that is a prefix of input file. It is not doing so. **for Ex: input --> 1.txt, 2.txt output should be 1.DI, 2.DI**

Comment: @LuisMendo I was about to answer just `dir`... ;)

Comment: I'd suggest [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) as a method for splitting the name and file extension without relying on a fixed extension length. A bit more robust but doesn't seem necessary for this case.

Comment: @excaza indeed. I added `fileparts` to the answer.