# How to read multiple images using a loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a folder with the images that I want to read into MATLAB and perform various built-in functions and matrix operations to those input images. 
Could anyone possibly help me figure it out?

Comment: Do you know how to read a single image?

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942514/matlab-iterate-function-on-all-files-in-a-directory -- as a possible continuation when you get a single image working.

Comment: yes @AndrasDeak I do know how to read a single one.

Comment: Sooo... do the single-reading thing, in a loop. Set up your filename with string concatenation, and store the image in either a cell (see below) or a multidimensional array.

Comment: I am not very familiar with programming. I would appreciate if you could use slightly layman language and not programming language.  If it helps: 

C:\Users\bm\Documents\MATLAB\FR  is my directory and i have files named as im1, im2... etc.

Comment: Literally one word different in the title than the duplicate. Next time search Stackoverflow

Comment: I had explained in my question that I don't understand the  solution given in other answers and I wanted help someone explaining it. My question was edited and I am new here. 

try being less rude next time.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your images are `.jpg`:

```
files = dir('directory*.jpg');
for i=1:length(files)
    images{i} = imread(files(i).name);
end
```

reads all images in current directory into cell array `images`

this one reads from `directory`:

```
directory = 'path to your directory';
files = dir([directory '/*.jpg']);
for i=1:length(files)
    images{i} = imread([directory '/' files(i).name]);
end
```